# Overflow issue in header causing Horizontal Scrolling on Mobile?

Tags: css

As the title says, i am getting a horizontal scrolling on mobile devices due to a possible header overflow issue. But i cant seem to pin the issue down using Developer Tools on Chrome.

Now there is a lot of code in the header and the css files are all over the place since its a wordpress theme so ill give you a link to check it out:
lendenapp.com.

Before i was using html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }, however it was causing some issue in the body.

I would like to find a way using css which will stop the horizontal scroll issue on the content on mobile devices.

Thanks guys
Alex

Comment: what about width of your header...?? if you have not added width then add width and try again

Comment: well i tried adding width: 100% to everything in the header but it still had the horizontal scrolling

Comment: have you heard about bootstrap..??try to use bootstrap....which provides you horizontal management

Comment: This would be the result:     


http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/u4kMs/8/